# lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am getting an error with Python that I am not able to understand. I have simplified my code to the very bare minimum:

```
response = requests.get('http://pycoders.com/archive')
tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
r = tree.xpath('//divass="campaign"]/a/@href')
print(r)
```

and still get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ultimate-1.py", line 17, in <module>
r = tree.xpath('//divass="campaign"]/a/@href')
File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 1509, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:50702)
File "xpath.pxi", line 318, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:145954)
File "xpath.pxi", line 238, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:144962)
File "xpath.pxi", line 224, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._raise_eval_error (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:144817)
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

Would anyone have an idea of where the issue is coming from? Might it be a dependencies problem? Thanks.

Comment: '//divass' is a straight syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `'//divass="campaign"]/a/@href'` is not syntactically correct and does not make much sense. Instead you meant to check the `class` attribute:

```
//div[@class="campaign"]/a/@href
```

Now, that would help to avoid the Invalid Expression error, but you would get nothing found by the expression. This is because the data is not there in the response that `requests` receives. You would need to mimic what the browser does to get the desired data and make an additional  request to get the javascript file containing the campaigns.

Here is what works for me:

```
import ast
import re

import requests
from lxml import html

with requests.Session() as session:
    # extract script url
    response = session.get('http://pycoders.com/archive')
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    script_url = tree.xpath("//script[contains(@src, 'generate-js')]/@src")[0]

    # get the script
    response = session.get(script_url)
    data = ast.literal_eval(re.match(r'document.write\((.*?)\);$', response.content).group(1))

    # extract the desired data
    tree = html.fromstring(data)
    campaigns = [item.attrib["href"].replace("\\", "") for item in tree.xpath('//div[@class="campaign"]/a')]
    print(campaigns)
```

Prints:

```
['http://us4.campaign-archive2.com/?u=9735795484d2e4c204da82a29&id=3384ab2140', 
 ...
 'http://us4.campaign-archive2.com/?u=9735795484d2e4c204da82a29&id=8b91cb0481'
]
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to do response.content.decode('utf-8') to have it work.

Answer (score 0):

U was wrong in making xpath. 
If u want to take all hrefs your xpath should be like

```
hrefs = tree.xpath('//div[@class="campaign"]/a')
for href in hrefs:
    print(href.get('href'))
```

or in one line:

```
hrefs = [item.get('href') for item in tree.xpath('//div[@class="campaign"]/a')]
```